# ASP.NET and C# - TextBox Value passed as Empty String to Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have CreateAccount.aspx and CreateAccount.aspx.cs

in CreateAccount.aspx I have the following control:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="UserName" runat="server" Text="User Name:" /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox id="inputUserName" type="text" runat="server" /></td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRV" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                ControlToValidate="inputUserName" Text="User Name Required!" />
    </tr>
```

and

```
<tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="newUserButton" Type="Submit" runat="server" Text="Create User" OnClick="newUserButton_Click" 
            UseSubmitBehavior="False" CausesValidation="false"/></td>
    </tr>
```

in CreateAccount.aspx.cs the code starts like this:

```
public partial class CreateAccount : System.Web.UI.Page {protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}

    protected void newUserButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {

        String UserName = inputUserName.Text;
        Label1.Text = UserName;
```

Label1.Text = UserName; is simply my attempt to validate that the data from the newUserButton_Click event is passed from the ASP control to the C# code behind.

However it is always passed as an empty string (not to be confused with NULL).

I know this because the Label is empty (not null) and the Database is an empty cell in cells which are designated as NOT NULL required.

I have tried researching multiple solutions and I am currently stumped.

I'm about 90% sure it's something incredibly simple that I've overlooked.

Comment: Make sure either your page or master page has form control with runat="server" and also your current control is part of form.(Inside that form)

Comment: Not `Label1.Text` but `UserName.Text`. Don't use `UserName` to name a label, it gets confusing with an actual user name value. Use something like `lblUserName`. This doesn't answer the database question, but start with the label to see if the value is there. Is the validation working?

Comment: I'm afk for a few hours but I'll double check my *.aspx and master pages for a form control with runat="server" when I get home

Comment: No issues with the master page having the form control with runat=server.

Comment: I re-built the master page and Create account page (mostly just copy paste) and magically the TextBox is no longer passing an empty string.  I don't know what's different other than I somehow cleaned up the form runat=server